# Can't start SQL Server 2008 - weird path in the log

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2008, service

I know there are thousands of questions about staring SQL Server, but I can't find the solution to my problem.

I can't start it and the log file reads: CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 21(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'I:\MSSQL\TempDB\tempdb.mdf'.

Server installed by default to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER

Why does it try to create temp DB on the I: drive? how can I change it?

Thakns